# How to interleave two txt files with alternative number of lines

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, cat

#### file1.txt:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

#### file2.txt:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

#### Desired output in 3 : 1 ratio (file3.txt)

```
1
2
3
A
4
5
6
B
```

#### Commands I have tried:

1. `sed Rfile2.txt file1.txt >file3.txt`
2. `paste -d '\n' file1.txt file2.txt >file3.txt`

Answer (score 9):

With `paste`:

```
paste -d '\n' <file1.txt - - - file2.txt
```

though it would keep outputting lines after one of the files is exhausted if there are still lines left in the other file as in your sample.

With `awk`:

```
awk '{print}; NR % 3 == 0 {getline < "file2.txt"; print}' file1.txt
```

Or the GNU `sed` equivalent:

```
sed '3~3 R file2.txt' file1.txt
```

This time, stop as soon as `file1.txt` is exhausted but still carry on if `file2.txt` is exhausted (and output empty lines in the `awk` variant and nothing in the GNU `sed` variant).

To stop as soon as either file is exhausted:

```
awk '{print}
     NR % 3 == 0 {
       if ((getline < "file2.txt") <= 0) exit
       print
     }' file1.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk '{print} (FNR % 3)==0{getline<"file2.txt"; print}' file1.txt
1
2
3
A
4
5
6
B
```

How it works

- `print`

  This prints each line from file1.txt.
- `(FNR % 3)==0{ getline <"file2.txt"; print}`

  On every third line, this prints a line from file2.txt.

#### Alternative

Some people strongly oppose use of awk's `getline`.  In that case:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0;next} {print} (FNR % 3)==0{print a[FNR/3]}' file2.txt file1.txt
1
2
3
A
4
5
6
B
```

How it works

- `FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0;next}`

  While reading the first file, `file2.txt`, we save its lines in array `a` and then skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` input line.
- `print`

  If we have gotten here, then we are reading the second file, `file1.txt` and we print its line.
- `(FNR % 3)==0 {print a[FNR/3]}`

  If the line number in file `file1.txt` is an even multiple of 3, then we print the line from file `file2.txt` whose line number is one third of the current line in `file1.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Using python:

#### Code:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rU') as f1, open(sys.argv[2], 'rU') as f2:
    while f1 or f2:
        for i, line in enumerate(f1):
            print line.strip()
            if i == 2:
                break
        if f2:
            try:
                print(next(f2).strip())
            except StopIteration:
                f2 = None
```

#### Results:

```
1
2
3
A
4
5
6
B
```